# CI Exception handler and Magento Autoload

Tags: ee2

I have a system that kind of "merges" ExpressionEngine and Magento. They are coupled in a number of ways and one of them is that we call Mage functionality from EE plugins.

This has just started happening and I can't determine when or where it is occuring.

Can anymoe help out here?

```
[18-Sep-2015 13:36:30] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: include(CI/Exceptions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /srv/www/htdocs/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93' in /srv/www/htdocs/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/www/htdocs/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(CI/Exce...', '/srv/www/htdocs...', 93, Array)
#1 /srv/www/htdocs/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php(93): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('CI_Exceptions')
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call('CI_Exceptions')
#4 /srv/www/htdocs/na_cms/codeigniter/system/core/Common.php(135): class_exists('CI_Exceptions')
#5 /srv/www/htdocs/na_cms/codeigniter/system/database/DB_driver.php(1172): load_class('Exceptions', 'core')
#6 /srv/www/htdocs/na_cms/codeigniter/system/database/DB_driver.php(330): CI_DB_driver->display_error(Array)
#7 /srv/www/htdocs/na_cms/expressionengine/libraries/Template.php(2806): CI_DB_driver->query('SE in /srv/www/htdocs/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 245
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[18-Sep-2015 13:36:30] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Warning: include(CI/Exceptions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /srv/www/htdocs/store/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93' in /srv/www/htdocs/store/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245`

Well, I would assume someone messed up your EE install (accidentally moved a folder or something). That path would look for that file in here: `/srv/www/htdocs/store/lib/Varien/CI/Exceptions.php`. Does it live there?

**Edit**

I also hate the autoload shit. Anyways, go to line 93 of that `Autoload.php` file, and try adjusting it to the full path of the `Exceptions.php` file. Probably something like `/srv/www/htdocs/system/codeigniter/CI/Exceptions.php`.

Not sure with your setup. Try SSH'ing in, and navigate to `/srv/www/htdocs/`. Then pull one of these suckers:

```
$ find . -name "Exceptions.php"
```

That'll locate that file.

This may all be bullocks since you have an interesting setup. Let me know.

Comment: No, Varien is the Magento stuff. No CI or EE units in the /store directory at all. I really dislike the Magento autoload, it has caused me more than one headache.

Comment: I edited my answer. It's a long shot.

Comment: no, it still isn't that. Magento should NOT be attempting to autoload anything from EE.

Comment: I found out what was causing this issue and remedied it. I was calling Mage::app in a template and you cannot do that, you have to write an EE plugin.

Comment: I would have never gotten there, lol. Glad you got it.